# What is the proper plural of the word "freshman"?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, north-american-english

Would it be proper to say *freshman students*, *freshmen*, or *freshmen students?*

**Edit:**

It is worth noting that I have since learned it is more acceptable in educational circles to use the term "first-year students" instead of "freshmen".

Comment: Note *freshman* (*freshmen*) is US and *fresher* (*freshers*) is UK. At least *fresher* is informal and I suspect the same for *freshman*.

Comment: @Hugo What are female first-year students called? are they freshwomen?

Comment: @WS2: In the UK it's just *freshers* and I don't know about the US but I suspect *freshmen* is used or just *first years*.

Comment: @Hugo  Pity, I rather liked the idea of 'freshwomen'!

Comment: @GEdgar it is extremely common in my area that they are considered 'Fresh-meat' to much of the older years in schools.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both "freshmen" and "freshman students" are correct, but "freshmen students" is wrong. I think "freshmen" is the official term.

Comment: Yes, I would think in almost any context where "freshmen" is used it is clear that you are referring to students. You could imagine contexts, however, where you need to distinguish between "freshman students" and "freshman senators" in which case "freshman ..." should be used.

Comment: To be PC, I always used to say Freshpersons.

Comment: @moioci: this is entirely a matter of personal preference, but I think "freshpersons" sounds weird.  I prefer "first-years."  There's a bit more of a risk of sounding pretentious, but that hasn't been a big problem for me.

Comment: I think "freshperson" is more pretentious than "freshman."

Comment: @moioci That's very speciest. You should say "freshbeings".

Comment: @Pops Weird? Not as weird as first-year university students in my neck of the world. They are called 'freshies'.

Answer (score 6):

In Canada, or at least in the part of Canada where I went to school, you can also say frosh. The singular and plural are the same. It can also be used as an adjective, as in frosh week, the first week of the term when the frosh are introduced to the school (and local pubs).

Comment: I heard that, too, in the Northeast US.  Though not at my school.   And at the University of Chicago, it was "first-years."

Comment: FWIW: We used that word in Oklahoma as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can also say "freshers", although I'm not sure if it's proper.

Comment: +1 "Freshers" is common usage in the UK. Fresher is in the OED as Pronunciation:/ˈfrɛʃə/  noun  British  informal term for freshman

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the definition of *freshman* on the *New Oxford American English*, I find two examples:

> We invited the freshmen.
>   [as adjective] A freshman second baseman.

In English, when a word is used as an adjective, the plural form of that word is not used.

> (*****) We invited the freshmen students.